# Вопрос по ООП PHP

Tags: ооп, php

Как реализовать подобную конструкцию?

```
class LogBase
 {
  function __construct() {}
  public function write($message)
   {
    fwrite(self::$file, "bla-bla");
   }
 }

class Log extends LogBase
{
 private $file = 'address/to/file'; 
}
```

(сокращённо).
То есть я хотел реализовать весь функционал в родительском (но не используемом классе), а, т.к. мне нужно несколько разных логов, создать классы-потомки, в которых будет указан путь к логу. Но если использовать

```
Log::write('something');
```

то `self::$file` в таком случае ведёт на родительский класс, в котором данной переменной, конечно, нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Late Static Bindings](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

> As of PHP 5.3.0, PHP implements a
> feature called late static bindings
> which can be used to reference the
> called class in a context of static
> inheritance.

```
class A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
    public static function test() {
        static::who(); // Here comes Late Static Bindings
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}

B::test();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class LogBase
{
    protected static $fHandle = false;

    protected function openFile()
    {
        if (self::$fHandle !== false) return true;
        self::$fHandle = fopen(static::FILE, 'a');
        return true;
    }

    public static function write($message)
    {
        self::openFile();
        fwrite(self::$fHandle, $message."\n");
    }
}

class Log extends LogBase
{
    const FILE = 'address_to_file';.
}

Log::write("sd");
```

Работать будет только с 5.3

То что вы хотите - называется "Позднее статическое связывание"

Comment: Спасибо большое всем, я не знал про такую вещь.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
class LogBase
 {
  protected $file;  // эта переменная будет доступной в наследниках и в данном классе
  function __construct($log_file) {$file = $log_file;}
  public function write($message)
   {
    fwrite($file, "bla-bla");
   }
 }

class Log extends LogBase
{
// данный объект можно конструировать, используя родительский конструктор 
...
}

$log = new Log('address/to/file'); // К примеру
$log->write("что-то записывается в файл...");
```

Comment: В том то и дело, то мне нужны неинстанциированные классы (то есть не объекты), поэтому пользоваться конструктором нельзя.

Comment: В таком случае я вас не совсем понимаю. Можете чуть-чуть поподробнее рассказать о своей задаче?

Comment: Всё просто. Мне нужно несколько логов (у них разные файлы), но функционал то один и тот же. А именно классы (не объекты) мне нужны для видимости везде в приложении.  
P.S.: я знаю, что есть и другие способы.